# undefined method for nil:NilClass error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following instance variables defined in a Rails controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def about
    @story, @story2 = Post.tagged_with("test").all(order: "RANDOM()", limit: 2)
  end
end
```

However, when I try to use the variable in a view page I get the following error:
`NoMethodError in Pages#about`
`undefined method user for nil:NilClass`

Nothing in the view seems to work. Here's the part of the view throwing the error:

```
 <% if @story.user.photo_file_name.present? %>
      <%= image_tag @story.user.photo.url(:avatar) %>
   <% else %>
      <%= image_tag('avatar.png', :size => "50x50") %>
 <% end %>
```

I don't see a problem with the variable definition in the controller. What is causing the error?

Thanks!!

Comment: well the actual error is unrelated to the code - what are you calling `user` on? Can we get the full error?

Comment: Doh! Bonehead mistake on my part. Sorry about that! I just updated my question

Comment: Perhaps `Post.tagged_with("test").all(order: "RANDOM()", limit: 2)` returns an empty array (aka there are no matching stories)?

Comment: Yup, that's it. I can't believe it was that simple! UGH! I only had 1 but I had a limit of 2 (as well as there being 2 variables). SOLVED! thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have no posts, so the `@story` is `nil`

Comment: Take a closer read at jmromer's answer and spickermann's comment. It's an answer, but some additional explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Your instance variables aren't being populated, so your query must not be returning anything. Either there's nothing in the database matching what you're looking for, or the request is malformed.

If you're certain you have matching records in the DB, I would try this as an alternative to see if it helps:

```
@story, @story2 = Post.tagged_with("test").order("RANDOM()").limit(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

As other people told you already, something in your code gets nil value and it shouldn't. Use pry to debug your code,

1. see http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails
2. put `binding.pry` at beginning of `PagesController#about` and start playing